# Colormath function delta_e_cie2000() not working properly

Tags: python, numpy, rgb, colormath

My goal is to calculate the difference between two RGB color values. When I run this example:

```
from colormath.color_objects import sRGBColor, LabColor
from colormath.color_conversions import convert_color
from colormath.color_diff import delta_e_cie2000

# Red Color
color1_rgb = sRGBColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

# Blue Color
color2_rgb = sRGBColor(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

# Convert from RGB to Lab Color Space
color1_lab = convert_color(color1_rgb, LabColor);

# Convert from RGB to Lab Color Space
color2_lab = convert_color(color2_rgb, LabColor);

# Find the color difference
delta_e = delta_e_cie2000(color1_lab, color2_lab);

print ("The difference between the 2 color = ", delta_e)
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'asscalar'
```

I tested it also on Google Collab to figure out if it was a configuration problem of my enviroment but I got the same error. I remember it was working properly before one month I think. Any clue what is happening or at least how to measure the `delta_e_cie2000` distance between two colors?

Comment: See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.16.0-notes.html#new-deprecations and https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.23.0-notes.html#expired-deprecations

Comment: See also https://github.com/gtaylor/python-colormath/issues/104

Comment: the code from GitHub worked fine that defines "patch_asscalar", thanks a lot